# Defining dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

1) I have a sheet named `C.A.`
I want to copy the range starting from `B$3` to the last cell (which is of column `H`)

2) Then paste it to another sheet called `2017`
To 2 cells below the (last cell of column `B` containing data)

I did the second one, but, cant define the first one.

```
Dim lastRow As String

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 2
Range("B" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you struggling with? You did not ask a question. This is not a free code writing service. We're happy to help you with your own effort, if you post what you have so far.

Comment: Is the last edit ok for you to consider that I gave an effort on it? I just didn't write the code to not confuse others and to be simple.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while performing the required actions manually?  It will give you lots of code that you can edit to get rid of the superfluous lines and hopefully end up with something useful.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald yes I tried to do thet in the first place but I could not do the first copying thing, because the lenght of the file will change everyday. I did not know how to set that dynamic range manually. I just did not try shift+end process. I just realized that let me just try that. thank you

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Thank you Mr. Fitzgerald, That worked now.

Comment: @efecantercan If my code work Accept the answer

Comment: @Marius That absulateley worked for me. It is doing the same with my manual recorded code but more seems like robust and smooth . Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim ws_ca As Worksheet
Dim ws_17 As Worksheet
Dim nr_2017 As Long
Dim nr_ca As Long

Set ws_ca = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C.A.")
Set ws_17 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2017")

nr_ca = ws_ca.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
nr_2017 = ws_17.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

ws_17.Range("B" & nr_2017 + 3 & ":H" & nr_2017 + nr_ca).Value = ws_ca.Range("B3:H" & nr_ca).Value
```